# Tidy and Cast Data With Headers Stuck in Rows

Tags: r, tidyr, reshape2

```
demodf <- data.frame(
  name = c("Mike","Mike","Mike","Mike","Mike","Joe","Joe","Joe","Joe","Joe"),
  Field = c("EDUCATION","Degree","Title","WORK", "Title", "EDUCATION","Degree","Title", "WORK","Title"),
  Values = c("EDUCATION", "Masters", "Student", "WORK", "VP Sales", "EDUCATION", "Bachelors","Student", "WORK", "Analyst"))

   name     Field    Values
1  Mike EDUCATION EDUCATION
2  Mike    Degree   Masters
3  Mike     Title   Student
4  Mike      WORK      WORK
5  Mike     Title  VP Sales
6   Joe EDUCATION EDUCATION
7   Joe    Degree  Bachelors
8   Joe     Title   Student
9   Joe      WORK      WORK
10  Joe     Title   Analyst
```

I want to `tidyr::spread` or `reshape2::dcast` into wide format, where `Field` becomes the column headers.

That code would  look like `dcast(demodf, name ~ Values)` or `demodf %>% spread(Field, Values)`. However, `dcast` coerces to numeric, and `spread` throws an error.

The problem is that "Title" repeats. You can see that due to a quirk in the data, we have EDUCATION and WORK as "false" headers within the data. Is it possible to tag each `Field` entry with the capitalized header so that `dcast` will work (i.e. `Title_EDUCATION`, and `Title_WORK`)? And it would be even better to apply that transformation to the whole `Field`, so "EDUCATION" and "WORK" disappear all together, and we're left with `Degree_EDUCATION, TITLE_EDUCATION`... etc.).

Note that there are many more headers in the actual data, so it would be best to identify the "false headers" as the all-cap entries, or the entries where `Field == Values`

Desired output:

```
output <- data.frame(
 Name=c("Mike", "Joe"),
 Degree_EDUCATION =c("Masters", "Bachelors"),
 Title_EDUCATION = c("Student", "Student"),
 Title_WORK= c("VP Sales", "Analyst"))

  Name Degree_EDUCATION Title_EDUCATION Title_WORK
1 Mike          Masters         Student   VP Sales
2  Joe        Bachelors         Student    Analyst
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to add that repeated category line as a new column, then you can work with it easily.

First, adding `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` so can compare `Field` and `Values`:

```
demodf <- data.frame(
  name = c("Mike","Mike","Mike","Mike","Mike","Joe","Joe","Joe","Joe","Joe"),
  Field = c("EDUCATION","Degree","Title","WORK", "Title", "EDUCATION","Degree","Title", "WORK","Title"),
  Values = c("EDUCATION", "Masters", "Student", "WORK", "VP Sales", "EDUCATION", "Bachelors","Student", "WORK", "Analyst"),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Now use `tidyr` and `dplyr` to add columns for if that row is a category and the name of that category, then to fill down the missing values, then to remove the extra rows and columns.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
d2 <- demodf %>% mutate(IsCategory=Field==Values,
                        Category=ifelse(IsCategory, Field, NA)) %>%
  fill(Category) %>% subset(!IsCategory, select=-IsCategory)
d2
##    name  Field    Values  Category
## 2  Mike Degree   Masters EDUCATION
## 3  Mike  Title   Student EDUCATION
## 5  Mike  Title  VP Sales      WORK
## 7   Joe Degree Bachelors EDUCATION
## 8   Joe  Title   Student EDUCATION
## 10  Joe  Title   Analyst      WORK
```

`dcast` will then work as you hope for!

```
library(reshape2)    
dcast(d2, name ~ Field+Category, value.var="Values")
##   name Degree_EDUCATION Title_EDUCATION Title_WORK
## 1  Joe        Bachelors         Student    Analyst
## 2 Mike          Masters         Student   VP Sales
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. The `mutate` bit to assign the `IsCategory` tag is a great trick.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt with `data.table`. This requires that stringsAsFactors=FALSE is used.

```
library(data.table)
# get groupings by titles (all caps)
setDT(demodf)[, head := cumsum(Field == toupper(Field))]
# merge titles onto full dataset and paste title to Field
demodf[demodf[Field == toupper(Field), .(Field, head)], on="head",
       Field := paste(Field, i.Field, sep="_"), by=.EACHI]
# now reshape wide
dcast(demodf[Values != toupper(Values),], name~Field, value.var="Values")
```

This returns

```
   name Degree_EDUCATION Title_EDUCATION Title_WORK
1:  Joe        Bachelors         Student    Analyst
2: Mike          Masters         Student   VP Sales
```

**data**

```
demodf <-
structure(list(name = c("Mike", "Mike", "Mike", "Mike", "Mike", 
"Joe", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe"), Field = c("EDUCATION", "Degree", 
"Title", "WORK", "Title", "EDUCATION", "Degree", "Title", "WORK", 
"Title"), Values = c("EDUCATION", "Masters", "Student", "WORK", 
"VP Sales", "EDUCATION", "Bachelors", "Student", "WORK", "Analyst"
)), .Names = c("name", "Field", "Values"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```