# Tidy data with variable in intermittent rows

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, data-wrangling

I have datalogger that inserts a row with a timestamp every time the logger is turned on. The timestamp string is always the same format, but there are an inconsistent number of readings per timestamp.

How do I tidy the timestamp rows into a `time` variable?

This previous question is close, except I want the data in the extra rows to be a variable, not a header (it's also four years old, and I suspect there's a more elegant tidyverse solution these days):
[Tidy and Cast Data With Headers Stuck in Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46550699/tidy-and-cast-data-with-headers-stuck-in-rows)

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_have <- tribble(
  ~site, ~n,  ~val,
  NA,  "Start 11:22:33", NA,
  "A", "N=1", .1,
  "A", "N=2", .3,
  NA,  "Start 12:33:44", NA,
  "B", "N=1", .2,
  "B", "N=2", .4,
  "B", "N=3", .6
)

df_want <- tribble(
  ~site, ~time, ~n,  ~val,
  "A", "11:22:33", "N=1", .1,
  "A", "11:22:33", "N=2", .3,
  "B", "12:33:44", "N=1", .2,
  "B", "12:33:44", "N=2", .4,
  "B", "12:33:44", "N=3", .6
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use `separate`, `fill`

```
df_have %>%
  separate("n", c("n","time"), sep=" ") %>% 
  fill(time) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  select(site, time, n, val)
```

Output:

```
  site  time     n       val
  <chr> <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
1 A     11:22:33 N=1     0.1
2 A     11:22:33 N=2     0.3
3 B     12:33:44 N=1     0.2
4 B     12:33:44 N=2     0.4
5 B     12:33:44 N=3     0.6
```

Comment: Great solution! I also learned two valuable points, thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you! Very elegant solution--just what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 3):

We could create a grouping column based on the 'Start' substring in 'n', create the 'time' by removing the 'Start' followed by one or more spaces (`\\s+`) in the 'first' element of 'n', remove the first row (`slice`) and `select` the columns of interest after `ungroup`ing

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
df_have %>% 
   group_by(grp = cumsum(str_detect(n, 'Start'))) %>%
   mutate(time = str_remove(first(n), 'Start\\s+')) %>%
   slice(-1) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(site, time, n, val)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
#  site  time     n       val
#  <chr> <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
#1 A     11:22:33 N=1     0.1
#2 A     11:22:33 N=2     0.3
#3 B     12:33:44 N=1     0.2
#4 B     12:33:44 N=2     0.4
#5 B     12:33:44 N=3     0.6
```

---

Or without grouping, we can `fill` after extracting the time component that follows the 'Start' and a space

```
df_have %>%
   mutate(time = str_extract(n, '(?<=Start\\s)\\S+')) %>%
   fill(time) %>% 
   filter(complete.cases(val))
```

Comment: Dear Arun may I ask what `(?<=Start\\s)` this part of your regex matches exactly? My knowledge of regex in non-existant basically.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR itis because of the behavior of str_extract to return NA if a row doesn't match, thus we can use `fill` in the later step after extracting the 11:22:33.  The pattern matches one or more non-white space (\\S+) that follows the 'Start' and space \\s

Comment: Thank you very much, I was just wondering about the `?<=` part, never really could wrap my head around it. By the way `fill` sounds amazing this is the first time I get to know it. This is actually one of those moments you once mentioned that someone makes mistakes or get something wrong but learn so much in return. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks akrun! I chose TarJae's solution to avoid the regex in this case, but your solution seems more adaptable to other cases.

Comment: @JMDR It's okay.  His solution is more concise

Comment: Can I ask a little more regex wizardry @akrun? It turns out that if my logger doesn't have a GPS attached the timestamp string is "Logger Started", if there is a GPS attached, the string is "Logger Started: 11:22:33" (note the extra colon after "Started")

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_have %>%
  mutate(time = replace(sub('Start\\s', '', n), !grepl('Start', n), NA)) %>%
  fill(time) %>%
  filter(!grepl('Start', n))

#  site  time     n       val
#  <chr> <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
#1 A     11:22:33 N=1     0.1
#2 A     11:22:33 N=2     0.3
#3 B     12:33:44 N=1     0.2
#4 B     12:33:44 N=2     0.4
#5 B     12:33:44 N=3     0.6
```