# Specify number of columns to read when first row is missing values

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-wrangling, readr

I have data from a logger that inserts timestamps as rows within the comma separated data. I've sorted out a way to wrangle those timestamps into a tidy data frame (thanks to the responses to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67350403/tidy-data-with-variable-in-intermittent-rows)).

The issue I'm having now is that the timestamp lines don't have the same number of comma-separated values as the data rows (3 vs 6), and `readr` is defaulting to reading only in only 3 columns, *despite* me manually specifying column types and names for 6. Last summer (when I last used the logger) `readr` read the data in correctly, but to my dismay the current version (2.1.1) throws a warning and lumps columns 3:6 all together. I'm hoping that there's some option for "correcting" back to the old behaviour, or some work-around solution I haven't thought of (editing the logger files is not an option).

Example code:

```
library(tidyverse)

# example data
txt1 <- "
,,Logger Start 12:34
-112,53,N=1,9,15,.25
-112,53,N=2,12,17,.17
"

# example without timestamp header
txt2 <- "
-112,53,N=1,9,15,.25
-112,53,N=2,12,17,.17
"

# throws warning and reads 3 columns
read_csv(
  txt1,
  col_names = c("lon", "lat", "n", "red", "nir", "NDVI"),
  col_types = "ddcddc"
)

# works correctly
read_csv(
  txt2,
  col_names = c("lon", "lat", "n", "red", "nir", "NDVI"),
  col_types = "ddcddc"
)

# this is the table that older readr versions would create
# and that I'm hoping to get back to
tribble(
  ~lon, ~lat, ~n, ~red, ~nir, ~NDVI,
    NA,   NA, "Logger Start 12:34", NA, NA, NA,
  -112,   53, "N=1", 9, 15, ".25",
  -112,   53, "N=2",12, 17, ".17"
)
```

Comment: I think you should reconsider as to whether you really want that output. Storing two different types of information (timestamps and counts) in the same column is not good practice and will only cause more issues later.

Comment: I wrangle the timestamp into its own column and convert to posixct as the next step (see link in my post), but need to read it in first in the format it's in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the base `read.csv` then convert to typle if need be:

```
read.csv(text=txt1, header = FALSE,
     col.names = c("lon", "lat", "n", "red", "nir", "NDVI"))
   lon lat                  n red nir NDVI
1   NA  NA Logger Start 12:34  NA  NA   NA
2 -112  53                N=1   9  15 0.25
3 -112  53                N=2  12  17 0.17
```

Comment: Thanks! I read the documentation for ```read.csv``` and missed the argument to specify col.names, which is mentioned in the more general ```read.table``` section instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would use `read_lines` and `write_lines` to convert the "bad CSV" into "good CSV", and then read in the converted data.

Assuming you have a file `test.csv` like this:

```
,,Logger Start 12:34
-112,53,N=1,9,15,.25
-112,53,N=2,12,17,.17
```

Try something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

read_lines("test.csv") %>% 
  # assumes all timestamp lines are the same format
  gsub(",,Logger Start (.*?)$", "\\1,,,,,,", ., perl = TRUE) %>%
  # assumes that NDVI (last column) is always present and ends with a digit
  # you'll need to alter the regex if not the case 
  gsub("^(.*?\\d)$", ",\\1", ., perl = TRUE) %>% 
  write_lines("test_out.csv")
```

`test_out.csv` now looks like this:

```
12:34,,,,,,
,-112,53,N=1,9,15,.25
,-112,53,N=2,12,17,.17
```

So we now have 7 columns, the first is the timestamp.

This code reads the new file, fills in the missing timestamp values and removes rows where `n` is NA. You may not want to do that, I've assumed that `n` is only missing because of the original row with the timestamp.

```
mydata <- read_csv("test_out.csv", 
                   col_names = c("ts", "lon", "lat", "n", "red", "nir", "NDVI")) %>% 
  fill(ts) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(n))
```

The final `mydata`:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 7
  ts       lon   lat n       red   nir  NDVI
  <time> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 12:34   -112    53 N=1       9    15  0.25
2 12:34   -112    53 N=2      12    17  0.17
```